# Comparing columns in two data frame in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, both of them contain different number of columns.
I need to compare three fields between them to check if those are equal.

I tried following approach but its not working.

```
if(df_table_stats("rec_cnt").equals(df_aud("REC_CNT")) || df_table_stats("hashcount").equals(df_aud("HASH_CNT")) || round(df_table_stats("hashsum"),0).equals(round(df_aud("HASH_TTL"),0)))
    {
        println("Job executed succefully")
    }
```

`df_table_stats("rec_cnt")`, this returns Column rather than actual value hence condition becoming false.

Also, please explain difference between `df_table_stats.select("rec_cnt")` and `df_table_stats("rec_cnt")`.

Thanks.

Comment: Answering your second question first, `df_table_stats("rec_cnt")` is a `Column` reference.  You would typically use such a reference when performing a join or in your dataframe projection.  `df_table_stats.select("rec_cnt")` returns a DataFrame with one column (rec_cnt).

You need to be more specific about what you mean by "compare three fields between them".  DataFrames are _collections_ of data.  What, specifically, do you need to compare?

Comment: I want to check those three fields from datagrams. If they are equal then print message that "Job ran successfully".

Comment: Can you be more specific?  A dataframe has several rows, each row with one or more columns.  Using that terminology, what specifically are you trying to check?  That the first row has specific values for specific fields?

Comment: Both dataframes have single row only. I want to compare column(3 named column) between them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per my comment, the syntax you're using are simple column references, they don't actually return data.  Assuming you **MUST** use Spark for this, you'd want a method that actually returns the data, known in Spark as an `action`.  For this case you can use `take` to return the first `Row` of data and extract the desired columns:

```
val tableStatsRow: Row = df_table_stats.take(1).head
val audRow: Row = df_aud.take(1).head

val tableStatsRecCount = tableStatsRow.getAs[Int]("rec_cnt")
val audRecCount = audRow.getAs[Int]("REC_CNT")

//repeat for the other values you need to capture
```

However, Spark **definitely** is overkill if this is all you're using it for.  You could use a simple JDBC library for Scala like [ScalikeJDBC](http://scalikejdbc.org/) to do these queries and capture the primitives in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql and inner join both df  , with your conditions .